# How to add a property with a custom type to Node's Global interface

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out how to add a property of MongoDB's `Db` type to Node's Global interface. Here is what I currently have:

```
// file vendor.d.ts
/// <reference types="mongodb" />

declare namespace NodeJS{
  interface Global {
    db: Db
  }
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
vendor.d.ts(5,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Db'.
```

If I change the type to `string` or even `Buffer` I get no error. Also, I can access the `Db` type in my other code just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are consuming the mongodb type declarations incorrectly

Try this

```
import  {Db} from 'mongodb';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      // Always name constructors with an initial capital letter.
      Db: typeof Db;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that by adding a top level `import` we have changed the source type/goal of the importing file, making it a module. This is also what necessitates the `declare global` block wrapping the declarations. Inside a module, all declarations are lexically scoped to the module body. The `declare global` syntax was introduced to enable modifying the *ambient* global scope from within a module.

Because it is now a module, it also changes the semantics of any code other code in the file so I recommend that you move it out of **vendor.d.ts**.

For example, you might create a file called **augmentations.d.ts** and place it in the root of your project.

Comment: How would I go about consuming this? As it is I get the error that the property `db` does not exist on type `Global`.

Comment: It depends on how your project is structured, what module format are you using? Do you use the files property in tsconfig.json? With a default tsconfig setup, the above just works. You must be on at least TypeScript 2.0.

Comment: Also note I didn't name the property `db` but rather `Db` because you should never have a constructable that starts with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm sorry, I was so focused on your comment that I'm not consuming mongodb correctly that I totally missed that you've also wrapped the namespace within that `declare global`! That was what I've been missing. :) It works now, thank you!